# Generate pseudo-random looking number from int

Tags: ruby, algorithm, random

I have an input string with this form:

```
<single char><int starting at 1, going up>
```

and want to produce, for each:

```
<the same single char><a unique 8 digit number>
```

I.e.:

```
"s1" => "s78138782"
"t1" => "t18743682"
"t2" => "t49274876"
```

Not allowed - we've already used that 8-digit number:

```
"t1" => "t78138782"
```

This doesn't need to be reversible, i.e., I don't need to be able to convert "`s78138782`" back into `s1` algorithmically. I'm saving them both in the database so I can look it up. I just want the numbers to look random as I step up through `t1`, `t2`, `t3`, etc., and to not be repeated.

Obviously the 8-character number will place a limit on the number of unique starting strings I can have: I'm fine with that at this stage.

Can anyone give me an algorithm for this?  I'm doing this in Ruby so Ruby would be ideal, and ideally using the standard Ruby/Rails gems.

Comment: Just generate a random number and put a unique index on its field in the db.

Comment: Sorry @SergioTulentsev, i don't understand.  Can you explain a little more how that solves my problem?

Comment: Unique index solves the repetition problem, you won't be able to insert the same value twice. And `rand()` will take care of the randomness.

Comment: When you say "I want the numbers to look random", does it have to be deterministic ? In that case, what about hashing the strings ?

Comment: WHY you want to do this is important, because what you are asking isn't likely to succeed over time. Do you want the unique numbers to be truly unique in the database, or "kinda-unique"? Generating a value outside the database and expecting it to be unique always is going to fail. A better solution is to ask the database to generate a sequence and insert the next value when you insert a record. We do that in databases often. If you generate a big number and have the DB convert it to a MD5 or base 64 value it'll appear random to anyone seeing it out of context, while maintaining uniqueness.

Comment: It is not clear what role the single alphabet character is playing.

Comment: @sawa - i generate these tokens (which are signup codes) and associate them with different classes of other objects.  The letter is a "quick-glance" indicator of what type of object it's been associated with.  So if someone phones up and says "my signup code doesn't work - it's t21872892" the person taking the call knows what type of code they've been given before they go and look in up in the db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common solution to this problem, which has the benefit of being reversible, is to select a random encryption key for the database, and then encrypt each input string. In order to make the target strings the right size, you first pad the input strings with some character which cannot be part of the string, such as a space.

Note that this procedure is not secure, but it is pseudo-random (or at least, it looks random) and it avoids any chance of collision.

Unfortunately, I don't know anything about Ruby, but I threw together this example in Python:

```
import Crypto.Cipher.Blowfish
import re
import struct

parse_id = re.compile("^(\D+)(\d+)$")
cipher = Crypto.Cipher.Blowfish.new("badsecret",
                                     Crypto.Cipher.Blowfish.MODE_ECB)

def randomize(id):
  pfx, integer = parse_id.match(id).groups()
  return "%c%d" % (
    pfx,
    struct.unpack("!Q",
                  cipher.encrypt(pfx
                  + struct.pack("!Q",
                                int(integer))[len(pfx):]))[0])
```

Then I tested it:

```
>>> for i in range(8): print ("t" + str(i), randomize("t" + str(i)))
... 
('t0', 't8812720357104479300')
('t1', 't14570648240240394176')
('t2', 't13775280166960833565')
('t3', 't6391672674195357485')
('t4', 't3595757360042384213')
('t5', 't10728238663553328366')
('t6', 't888684936954575988')
('t7', 't9447169127882289438')
>>> for i in range(8): print ("s" + str(i), randomize("s" + str(i)))
... 
('s0', 's9209414168426526439')
('s1', 's5452467189798635654')
('s2', 's10995755223696930463')
('s3', 's1237785964853872245')
('s4', 's4976813073866522017')
('s5', 's17045636624557288261')
('s6', 's14217087933089289315')
('s7', 's3504968071130220057')
```

Making the numbers shorter requires finding a block cipher with a smaller block or using a stream cipher. I don't know what Ruby has to offer in terms of crypto libraries. (Indeed, I barely knew anything about Python's crypto support before I edited this answer.)

Comment: that sounds interesting, can you give an example, ideally in ruby?  thanks!

Comment: @MaxWilliams: Python is the best I can do, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking for a pseudo random looking numberI would just generate a random number using the rand() function and add the index to the random number that way you don't have to worry about collisions.